# Android webview app not working properly in Android 4.4 or lower

Tags: android, jquery, webview, admob, hybrid-mobile-app

I have create one Android app using android webview. I am using jQuery mobile. I am also using Admob  and javascriptInterface in that.  The app is working fine in Android 5.0 and higher, but it is opening and stucking on pageload in lower versions of Android. 
I have set minimum API level to 15 and max to 26.

What could be  the possible  reason for this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem.
WebView in 4.4 or lower versions of android does not support CSS animations, that caused my page to stuck. 
So, I used -webkit- vendor prefix for chrome, then it worked fine.